# Eliminate Rollover Behavior on <a> tag over an image

Tags: php, css, html

I have the following piece of code that functionally works well.

```
<div class="user-pic round-pic">
 <a href="<?php echo $userLoggedIn; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $user['profile_pic']; ?>"></a>
</div>
```

The problem is how it looks.  When I rollover the image to click, I get this weird half transparent gradient look.
[image: idle]
[image: on rollover]

I know it's a stupid pic but I'm working locally.  Here is the CSS for this pic:

```
round-pic img {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
object-fit: cover;
}
```

Any thoughts on how I could eliminate this rollover behavior?  Little things like this bother me not to mention detract from the UX.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I tried pointer-events: none; and this eliminates it alright, but then of course kills the link.

Comment: Did you check its not got css `img:hover{opacity:.9}` on the images etc?

Comment: @Lawrence, nice...a:hover, a:active{text-decoration: none;opacity: 0.95;color: inherit;}  found that tucked away.  How would I eliminate this for just this a tag?

Comment: target `.user-pic a` class and set `opacity: 1;`

Comment: I targeted the <a> tag and used inline to set to 1.  I kept trying to target hover knowing it's a psuedo class, pain in the a... :) Ne-who, thankyou, I appreciate you taking the time.

Comment: Are you saying the problem is solved now? In that case, you should post an answer yourself. If not, can you show the CSS for the .user-pic class?

Answer (score 0):

Based on a forum suggestion I discovered `img:hover{opacity: 0.95}` was set in main.css.  I simply targeted the `<a>` tag and used inline to change the style.

```
<a href="#" style="opacity: 1;"><img src="assets/images/profile_pics/blarg.jpeg"></a>
```

Not a huge issue obviously, but needed to be corrected nonetheless.